# generate component is not creating reference in app module in angular

Tags: angular, components

When Generate component is not creating reference in app module in angular when using ng g c component name.

1. I am trying to create component using CLI but it is not updating app module with reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
ng g component ComponentName --module=app.module.ts
```

Because maybe you have multiple modules.

Also please try to provide us with a sample of your file structure.

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me

```
ng g component path/components/ComponentName --module=app.module
```

**app.module** whitout **.ts**